# Better approach for implementing 2 similar classes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am importing and exporting from [the XPDL standard](http://www.wfmc.org/xpdl.html) using C#.

I have written a hierarchy for classes using [XPDL 2.1](http://www.xpdl.org/documents.html) and have debugged serialization with `XmlSerializer`. I need to implement [XPDL 2.2](http://www.xpdl.org/standards/xpdl-2.2/XPDL%202.2%20%282012-08-30%29.pdf).

The structure of the classes has changed. There are additional parameters as well. There was list of `Artifacts` which was child of the root class, but the newer version lost `DataObject` from all of Artifacts. The DataObjects moved from an additional List into `WorkflowProcess`.

I need to support [XPDL 2.1](http://www.xpdl.org/documents.html) and [XPDL 2.2](http://www.xpdl.org/standards/xpdl-2.2/XPDL%202.2%20%282012-08-30%29.pdf). What is the best way to implement both of them?

I can see **3** ways:

1. Copy and paste existing hierarchy with needed fixes (it is awful!)
2. Create a base class and create two child classes. One for 2.1 and another for 2.2 (but will not it be too complex to maintain?)
3. Implement conditional serialization using an `enum` variable. The class will contain the super-set of 2.1 and 2.2 (This option seems overly complex)

Please let me know if there is a better approach.

Comment: Not really an "answer" as such, but personally, I think the first option is the most "obviously correct", although it is more work.

The second is unlikely the work, as `XmlSerializer` is inheritance aware, and has particular ways of wanting to represent inheritance. The third looks overly complex, which us usually a synonym of "brittle".

Comment: Thanks for your comment, so you saying that first way is the easiest and thus I should implement it?

Comment: in reality, I expect that is your best option. If it was just a case of adding / not-adding a few elements/attributes, then you could handle that via "conditional serialization", but: to change the *structure*, you would either need to implement `IXmlSerializable` (which is **seriously** painful), or you would need to start with different structures.

Comment: Thank you again! I think I will take your advice

Comment: I tend to agree with Marc. We can assume 2.1 isn't going to change at all because that is why 2.2 was invented. And 2.2 won't change either. So implementing each as a separate project seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two additional seperate projects in your solution. The first should contain classes to be parsed from XPDL 2.1.

The second one is for 2.2, it should include all cs files from first's project folder as links. Instead of managing them manually add these lines to your second project file:

```
<Compile Include="..\ParserXPDL21\Classes\**\*.cs">
  <Link>Classes\file.cs</Link>
</Compile>
```

Remember to reload the second project each time you add or remove files from the first, otherwise Visual Studio will not compile it until you do.

For the second project declare a conditional constant in the project properties: XDPL22

Now you can modify the first project files like this to maintain two versions in the same file:

```
#if !XDPL22
namespace ParserXPDL21
#else
namespace ParserXPDL22
#endif
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Root
    {
#if !XDPL22
        public Artifact[] Artifacts { get; set; }
#endif
        public int NormalProperty1 { get; set; }
        public int NormalProperty2 { get; set; }
        public int NormalProperty3 { get; set; }

    }
}
```

After that you can reference these two projects from your main project and use the classes for the two different versions.

I know it doesn's seem to be a very elegant way but it helps when you have to make a lot of duplicated code.

You still need a way to check what version of XPDL you are going to read. May be you can just look at the file extension but if it's the same than you can just try to read 2.2 and if it throws an exception or the data is not correct think this is 2.1, or you can read XML manually  with XmlReader and check before deserializing.